# Is there a way to let the user decide between two ListStyles in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

What I am trying to accomplish is a list which can change its style based on the user's preference.

I have a `@AppStorage` property which can be changed in the settings to use `.plain` or `.insetGrouped` in the `listStyle` modifier.

I have tried using a ternary operator like in the code below, but I get a type mismatch error. Here's my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("listStyle") private var listStyle: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { i in
                    Section {
                        Text("Item \(i)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(listStyle ? .plain : .insetGrouped)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom `ViewModifier` to apply the appropriate list style based on the boolean like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("listStyle") private var isListPlain: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { i in
                    Section {
                        Text("Item \(i)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .myListStyle(isListPlain: isListPlain)
        }
    }
}

struct MyListViewModifier : ViewModifier {
    let isListPlain : Bool
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if(isListPlain){
            content.listStyle(.plain)
        }else{
            content.listStyle(.insetGrouped)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func myListStyle(isListPlain : Bool) -> some View {
        modifier(MyListViewModifier(isListPlain: isListPlain))
    }
}
```